# How to create panoramic image using a set of images

Tags: image, computer-vision, panoramas

I am a newbie in image processing and I have taken a project of creating a panoramic image from a set of images and I don't know how to get started on this .What all things I have to learn ?
Thank You in advance

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been tagged "sift". This is not a question about SIFT. There are numerous types of features that could be used for aligning projections. You don't even need features; you can use direct methods if the set of images are suitable.

Comment: What I got searching net is that almost everywhere SIFT is used for features and  having said that can you please tell me what are the direct methods as it would be great help for me.Thank You

Comment: SIFT is only one type of feature. Harris corners and KLT features have been widely used for mosaicing. For more info on direct vs. indirect see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation and the Szeliski book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very good reference:

Matthew Brown and David G. Lowe, "*[Automatic panoramic image stitching using invariant features](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/papers/ijcv2007.pdf)*," International Journal of Computer Vision, 74, 1 (2007), pp. 59-73.

The process is basically this:

1. Extract image features at repeatable keypoints.
2. Do image-to-image matching to find out overlap areas between images.
3. Do bundle adjustment to align all the matching images.
4. Rendering tricks so that the output looks nice.

The above reference uses SIFT features, described in this paper:

David G. Lowe, "*[Distinctive image features from scale-invariant keypoints](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf)*," International Journal of Computer Vision, 60, 2 (2004), pp. 91-110.

Prerequisites to understanding this material include:

- [image gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient)
- interest points ([corner detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection), [difference of gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians))
- descriptor types (simple image patches, SIFT, SURF)
- approximate [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) (I'd suggest using the [FLANN](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN) library for this)
- [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC)
- linear algebra (especially [homographies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography))
- [non-linear least-squares minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) techniques (like the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm))

Koan suggests an excellent textbook in his answer.

It's possible to use a lot of existing code to do feature extraction ([VlFeat](http://vlfeat.org/) provides Matlab and C++ libraries), RANSAC, and minimization (I don't know what the best libraries are for those, though). OpenCV is also a very good computer vision library.

How long do you have for this project? I think it's quite ambitions. Based on having no experience in computer vision, I think a pretty good goal would be to find the transformation between just *two images* and stitch them together. You'd learn a lot just from that.

Comment: The asker is saying that they are a newbie and don't even know where to start; and you are talking about features, homographies and bundle adjustment! Your answer must look like hieroglyphs

Comment: @koan They knew enough to tag it with SIFT, and they were asking for a list of things to learn, so, that's what my answer is.

Comment: Actually the main problem that I am facing is that although I have access to all international research  papers on panoramic images creation which has been mention by Sancho also  but I don't have the prerequisites  to understand the process they are applying .It would be great help if  you can tell me what  are the prerequisites for understanding them .

Comment: Note:I am a final year student of Computer engineering (under graduate) .I don't know anything of image processing.

Comment: @Sancho I have 3.5 months to implement a research paper on creation of panoramic images .Do you think that it is possible (realistically) for a newbie like me to do it?

Comment: @ankit It could be realistic, but it really depends on your familiarity with the mathematics, and how good of a software engineer you are (learning new libraries, debugging, testing, etc.) If you're not sure you can implement the full paper, you could propose a project with a more limited scope (like only some portions of the paper), and then if you have time, implement the full thing. I think your professor would likely agree to that.

Answer (score 2):

Get Richard Szeliski's excellent book [Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/) and look at chapter 9.

Comment: Thank You and I think it would help me to get started on my project .

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/hostings/cescg/CESCG-2006/papers/Szczecin-Ostiak-Piotr.pdf

This might help get you started.